# Max execution time out error when tried to download large object(2gb) from s3 bucket to window server using php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to download 2gb files to s3 bucket (using Amazon Simple Storage Service) to my window server 2008 r2 (save to C:/inetpub/wwwroot/projectname/filetostorefroms3 folder.) but I got below error -

```
Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded \S3.php on line 2308
```

Line 2308 started from private function as below in s3.php (tried using version 0.2.3 and 0.5.1).

```
private function __responseWriteCallback(&$curl, &$data)
    {
        if (in_array($this->response->code, array(200, 206)) && $this->fp !== false)
            return fwrite($this->fp, $data);
        else
            $this->response->body .= $data;
        return strlen($data);
    }
```

Download object from s3 bucket script I am using as below. Using this script I downloaded object around 200MB. But when I tried 200Mb+ object then same error happened as stated above.

```
 <?php

if (!class_exists('S3'))
    require_once('S3.php');

//AWS access info
if (!defined('awsAccessKey'))
    define('awsAccessKey', 'aws-key-here');
if (!defined('awsSecretKey'))
    define('awsSecretKey', 'aws-secret-key-here');

//instantiate the class
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

$bucket = 'bucketname';
$FileHandle = fopen('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/projectname/filetostorefroms3/downloadobject.zip', 'w+');
$result = $s3->getObject($bucket, 'downloadobject.zip', $FileHandle
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
?>
```

Moreover, I tried using all three method mentioned in this official url - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/installation.html but got the same error.

I have also setup the web.config file in my window server 2008 r2 as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <fastCgi>
    <application fullPath="C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe" activityTimeout="2592000">
      <environmentVariables>
         <environmentVariable
            name="PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS"
            value="10000" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </application>
  </fastCgi>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My php.ini file as below

```
max_execution_time =3000 also set up - 259200
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 2000M
post_max_size = 1000M
```

Also tried using Amazon S3 Stream Wrapper but no luck so please guys help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/GettingObjectsUsingAPIs.html

> Retrieve object in parts—Using the Range HTTP header in a GET request,
>   you can retrieve a specific range of bytes in an object stored in
>   Amazon S3. You resume fetching other parts of the object whenever your
>   application is ready. This resumable download is useful when you need
>   only portions of your object data. It is also useful where network
>   connectivity is poor and you need to react to failures.

This way you can divide the request in multiple requests which each have their own request time.

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$bucket = '*** Your Bucket Name ***';
$keyname = '*** Your Object Key ***';
$filepath = '*** Your File Path ***';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory();
$HUNDRED_MB = 1024*100;

// Get a range of bytes from an object.
$result = $s3->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $keyname,
    'Range'  => 'bytes=0-$HUNDRED_MB'
));
```

You have to calculate the size of the chunks yourself. For 5GB / 300 seconds I suggest 100MB. 100 MB (0,33 MB/s is not an extreme expectation) and it makes for a nice 50 packages.

Comment: Can you give me some example how to do that?

Comment: I am downloading object through ajax request and also I tried your script as per your instruction but still got Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded.

Comment: @Chirag Weird, I'm sorry, but I have no idea how that still happens. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I run your code in my localhost and it's downloaded 10MB only from 400Mb so need to do the loop for getobject array able to download 400Mb?

Comment: If I follow this method then how I am suppose to merge those packages in single file?