# PHP website running on AWS ec2 (w/ apache), can't download over 64 Megabytes via the AWS SDK S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've been searching through the web quite a bit now, found several possible solutions, but none of them worked. Some say it's due to `php.ini` settings, some say it's due to the method I am using from the SDK. I'm a bit stuck here. I've tested it quite thoroughly, and with the current code I have, I am able to download a file from my S3 bucket without problems or corruptions, however it's **ALWAYS** limited to 64 megabytes.
Is there some way to up this limit? Or increment the download?

When I try to download a file over 64 megabytes the page cannot be reached. Sometimes it might actually download the file anyway (while it says cannot be reached), but only exactly 64 megabytes.

```
try {
    $result = $s3->getObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname
    ]);

    set_time_limit(0); 

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}; charset=utf-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);

    echo $result['Body'];

    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I've set my `memory_limit` to no limit (0). I've also tried to set the memory limit to about 64 megabytes, but still no dice.

Tried tinkering with `post_max_size` etc, but still nothing. I'm not sure if the problem relies on my apache/php setup, the EC2 I'm running, or S3 SDK limitations.

The EC2 instance I'm running is a `t2.xlarge`, running: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) LAMP Stack - Linux Apache MySQL/MariaDB PHP

Some of the things I've found with similar issues (The first one I've tried without luck):

[Download large files from s3 via php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60040595/download-large-files-from-s3-via-php) **<-- This link has solution**

[Max execution time out error when tried to download large object(2gb) from s3 bucket to window server using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765127/max-execution-time-out-error-when-tried-to-download-large-object2gb-from-s3-bu)

The bottom link I don't really understand, apparently the solution should be to increment the download (according to online Thomas), but I'm not sure how that would work. How would I combine the data, and how would I keep downloading from where I left off? I'm missing an example of how to work that solution. The OP of that post asked the same question.

Comment: From your t2.xlarge instance what is result of SELECT @@max_allowed_packet; ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The presigned request solution from OP from the first link, did solve my problem. However it's a different "way of downloading", before in my code we were using the SDK to download via the SDK, now we are using the SDK to create basically a download link. The 64 megabyte issue still persists. I can use this, but if anyone has a solution for how to download via the SDK over 64 megabytes, please let me know!

My solution:

```
$cmd = $s3->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $keyname,
    'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"'
]);

$request = $s3->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+15 min');
$presignedUrl = (string)$request->getUri();
```

And then basically just open that URL anywhere in HTML, JS etc. and it will begin to download the file.